# Are to-many Relationships order-preserving in Realm?

Tags: realm

I was wondering if to-many relationships in Realm are order-preserving. In the case of Objective-C the RLMArray type used for the relationship provides methods like **insertObject:atIndex:** which lets me suggest that it should be a relationship that preserves the ordering of the objects. Unfortunately I couldn't find reliable information stating that this fact is always guaranteed for those relations. Can anyone tell me if the order is guaranteed to be preserved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, RLMArray/List properties preserve their order of insertion in Realm. See https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#to-many-relationships